# What are these on the probes

Tags: voltage, current, oscilloscope, differential, lvds

I am having a Lecroy differential probe and trying to measure a LVDS signal. This is the [Reference Manual](http://cdn.teledynelecroy.com/files/manuals/wavelink-low-bandwidth-differential-probes-operators-manual.pdf) which I am referring to as a guide.

My differential probe tip/lead model number : [DX20 - SP/SI/QC](http://cdn.teledynelecroy.com/files/pdf/wavelink_low_bandwidth_datasheet.pdf). Please see its specification in the table present on the document. I am using the WL-PBUS2 Probus2 cable assembly with the D420-A Differential amplifier.

But can someone tell me what are circled in red items on the differential probe tip/lead assembly?

[image]

There seems to be 2 resistors in series with the +ve and the -ve differential line and one resistor across it. I tried to measure their values in multimeter. But it think, there is a layer of coating above those components because of which I am not able to measure their values using multimeter. I did not want to scratch the coating and try fearing it might damage the probe which is very expensive.

Can someone tell me what are the 3 components in the above image? I search and tried to read in the attached manual, but unable to find what those are and how do they help in measuring a differential signal.

Below is my setup :

[image]

I am connecting the above differential probe across the vias 1 and 3 to measure the LVDS Signal. I am getting random waveform which I know it is because of the termination mismatch at the probe shown above.

Please guide.

Comment: They are ... blurs!

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But I am unable to take a better clarity image since they are so small. I believe all the three small components are resistors.

Comment: If you hold the phone just a little further away, it will actually be able to focus.